# How to fix react-window height issue with react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-window

I'm using react-select with react-window but there is issue with height of dropdown like:

I have only two value but height is larger than items, How can i fix it? dropdown values coming from API that can be vary.

**Note: I also need to define maxHeight of dropdown.**

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-with-react-window-4k375c?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the height using react style to `max-content` fixes the issue here

```
  <List
    style={{ height: "max-content", maxHeight: maxHeight }}
    height={1}
    itemCount={children.length}
    itemSize={itemHeight}
    initialScrollOffset={initialOffset}
  >
    {({ index, style }) => <div style={style}>{children[index]}</div>}
  </List>
```

you still need to specify `height` since the component requires it but it can be any value the `max-content` will overwrite it. [This is](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-with-react-window-forked-652r3z?file=/src/App.js) a fixed fork of your issue

Comment: I also need to define maxHeight of dropdown.

Comment: @RohitVerma I've updated both the answer and the fork now it includes the maxHeight too.

Comment: If dropdown items will be more than 2-3 than its giving issue, can you please check codSandbox Again, I implemented your changes in codeSanbox link given in my question.

Comment: Thanks @Sarkar its working fine now, I updated my codeSandbox with solution...

Comment: can we make itemSize auto ? because item content is overlapping when large data... in dropdown options...